# How can I download the GarageBand program on my HP laptop?

Tags: keyboard, garage-band

How can I download the GarageBand program on my HP laptop? I need to send a score to my friend in another state for his next album, and I am using my Roland Juno DS 76 keyboard.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, this is off-topic for MusSE. You may try a scoring software like musescore, or you can even use trial versions of FL Studio or Ableton Live

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions on how to  install software are off-topic. You may be able to get an answer on the Super User SE.

Answer (score 6):

You can't install the official GarageBand on a Windows PC; it only exists for macOS and iOS. Fortunately, there are countless alternatives; [this article](https://garagebandforpcwindows.com/) lists some of them which you can maybe use.

You can either have such a program export a MIDI file (which records the notes you play, how long they are and with which velocity, but not the sound of your Roland keyboard, i.e. basically a transcription of the sheet music) or an audio file (WAV, OGG, MP3) - a MIDI file has the advantage that your friend can easily edit it. But their GarageBand will support importing both types.